# A sequence of subsets of an infinite group.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there an infinite group $G$ such there is **not** any sequence $(A_n)$  of its subsets such that always
$$A_n=A_n^{-1}, \quad A_{n+1}A_{n+1}\subsetneqq A_n$$
?

Comment: If such group exists, it has to be Artinian. The simplest example of Artintian infinite group is $R/Q$, the thing to do would be to check if such sequence exists for this example.

Comment: cross-posted in MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173391/a-sequence-of-subsets-of-an-infinite-group

Comment: @studiosus $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ does not work: Let $A_n$ be the $\mathbb Q$-llinear combinations of all $\sqrt{p_{n+k}}$, $k\ge 0$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.